# Gradle zip task gives NO-SOURCE

Tags: gradle

i have a gradle zip task, say 'X' that works fine for the first time. But after that it gives the following:

*Skipping task ':X' as it has no source files and no previous output files.*

my code is:

```
project.task("X", type: Zip) {
        String zipSrc = "/target/files"
        Path path= Paths.get("${project.rootDir}${zipSrc}")
        if(Files.exists(path)){
            archiveName = "${project.rootProject.name}-files.zip"
            destinationDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/libs")
            from "${zipSrc}"
        }
    }

project.tasks['X'].dependsOn('compileJava')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zip Task automatically checks if it has files to Zip, so no need to check with Files.exists(...).

In `from "${zipSrc}"`, `zipSrc`is treated as an absolute path `/target/files`

I think what you try to accomplish is

```
project.task("X", type: Zip) { 
    String zipSrc = "target/files" // zipSrc no longer absolute
    archiveName = "${project.rootProject.name}-files.zip"
    destinationDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/libs")
    from "${zipSrc}"
}
```